# No space on disk for .NET IIS App

Tags: .net, iis, quota

I have an IIS server running multiple apps.  When I checked the space available on the C:\ drive on that server it said 20GB free.  But I still get the following stack trace:

```
 [IOException: There is not enough space on the disk.
 ]
System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath) +7717304
System.IO.Directory.InternalCreateDirectory(String fullPath, String path, DirectorySecurity dirSecurity) +7569557
System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(String path, DirectorySecurity directorySecurity) +150
batchprocessor.btnUpload_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) +979
System.Web.UI.WebControls.LinkButton.OnClick(EventArgs e) +111
System.Web.UI.WebControls.LinkButton.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +79
     System.Web.UI.WebControls.LinkButton.System.Web.UI.IPostBackEventHandler.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +10
System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(IPostBackEventHandler sourceControl, String eventArgument) +13
System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(NameValueCollection postData) +175
System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +1565
```

Is there a separate quota somewhere?

Comment: It is hard to tell without knowing what is the value of fullPath - are you sure you are trying to write to the C drive?

Comment: that's a good point...i'll have to dig deeper

Comment: Are there quotas on C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\Framework\vX.XXXX\Temporary ASP.NET Files? Is that directory writable by the application pool?

Comment: it is writable...should i delete the temp internet files?  the sites were fine yesterday

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I heard of cases where the IWAM_ user has a quota set and you may be hitting it.

Comment: how do you check/alter this quota

Comment: You can see if Quotas are enabled by going to My Computer, right clicking on the drive, selecting properties and then the Quota tab.  If "Enable Quota Management" is not checked, it's probably not a user quota issue.

Comment: If you open Properties for the C: drive you should see a tab for Quota, if it is disabled then disconsider my answer.

Comment: you win, you were write: IIS Guest User was set to 200mb quota and had 199.99mb full.

Comment: You solved my problem, thanks! Anyway the user running IIS (6.0) was NETWORK SERVICE